# Ruby on Rails - Stuck on Chapter 9.3.3 of Hartl Book, undefined method sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working through 9.3.3 of the Hartl book and keep getting stuck with an

undefined method `sign_in' for SessionsController:0x00000100c0da90

I know that this is because the sign_in method is in the sessions_helper file, which is picked up by the model and not by the controller. The Hartl book does not require a "include SessionsHelper" line.

If I put in that hack, which I am assuming I shouldn't, it then ends up landing me with another error undefined method current_user

Here is the code

SessionsController.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @title = "Sign in"
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate( params[:session][:email],
                              params[:session][:password])
     if user.nil?
       flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combo."
       @title = "Sign in"
       render 'new'
     else
       sign_in user
       redirect_to user
     end 

 end

  def destroy
  end
```

and for sessions_helper.rb

```
  module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    self.current_user = user
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there should be an "include SessionsHelper" in the application controller. By default, helpers are included in the views but in order to make use of a helper in a controller, it needs to be included explicitly.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I don't know how I missed that box. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have already included SessionsHelper in your application_controller and are still getting this failing test error:

If you updated your spec/support/utilities.rb file in the exercises previously in Ch. 8 and used the example given, there is a good chance you created the "sign_in" method but named it "valid_signin" based on the example in the chapter 8 exercise rather than Listing 9.6 where it is named simply 'sign_in'. Hope this helps.

Also this is based on the 2nd Ed. of the tutorial but should still apply to the 1st I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth adding that you need to be careful not to get confused by the sign_in helper written in the SessionsHelper module, and the sign_in written in the spec/support/utilities.rb file.  Same name but two different functions.  In the tests the one being called is the one written in the utilities.rb file (Listing 9.6) and is as follows:

```
def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email",      with: user.email
  fill_in "Password",   with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  #sign in when not using capybara as well
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you have to `include SessionsHelper` in your ApplicationController? (Licting 9.11 in the book),and then define `current_user` in it (listing 9.14)?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I made was that I never put the utilities.rb file in a sub folder support