# RoR. Chapter 8, Section 8.2.4 - Undefined method for Signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm working on RoR tutorial, Chapter 8.  I am trying to complete section 8.2.4 - Changing the layout links and ran `$ bundle exec rspec spec/` and I got the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: click_button "Sign in"
     NoMethodError:
     undefined method `sign_in' for #<SessionsController:0x007fef66b85fd0>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: click_button "Sign in"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sign_in' for #<SessionsController:0x007fef66b33eb0>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: click_button "Sign in"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sign_in' for #<SessionsController:0x007fef6698bba8>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Authentication signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: click_button "Sign in"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sign_in' for #<SessionsController:0x007fef68286130>
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:35:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.34 seconds
44 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:39 # Authentication signin with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:40 # Authentication signin with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:38 # Authentication signin with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:41 # Authentication signin with valid information
```

Based on the output, I checked `spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb`, but I can't seem to find the error.  This is what I have:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

subject { page }

describe "signin page" do 
    before { visit signin_path } 

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
end

  describe "signin" do
before { visit signin_path }

describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Sign in" }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

    describe "after visiting antoher page" do 
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') } 
    end
end

    describe "with valid information" do 
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before do
            fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
            fill_in "Password", with: user.password
            click_button "Sign in"
        end

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
        it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
    end
end
end
```

I can't seem to find the error.  Any suggestions on where I should look based on the error output?  Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - Stuck on Chapter 9.3.3 of Hartl Book, undefined method sign\_in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038716/ruby-on-rails-stuck-on-chapter-9-3-3-of-hartl-book-undefined-method-sign-in) which indicates that there should be an "include SessionsHelper" in the application controller.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config/routes.rb file to make sure that:

```
match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
```

matches what your session controllers is seeing. The create method for your "sessions_controller.rb" should have:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    sign_in user
    redirect_back_or user
  else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Just my guess. I'm currently around that area too in the tutorial. Best of luck and I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late probably but anyways...

Check if you got "include SessionsHelper" in app/controllers/application_controller.rb

helpers are included into views by default but you have to explicitly include them in controllers